# How do I install the 'Data.List.Split' module for Haskell?

Tags: haskell, module, installation, cabal

I have been trying to import the 'Data.List.Split' module since yesterday. I looked around stack overflow for similar questions, but I couldn't find a definitive solution to my slightly basic problem.

This is what I wrote in the text editor (excluding comments).

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char
import System.IO

data Cell = Fixed Int | Possible [Int] deriving (Show, Eq)

type Grid = [Row]

readGrid :: String -> Maybe Grid
readGrid s
  | length s == 81 = traverse (traverse readCell) . Data.List.Split.chunksOf 9 $ s
  | otherwise      = Nothing
  where
     readCell '.' = Just $ Possible [1...9]
     readCell c
       | Data.Char.isDigit c && c > '0' = Just . Fixed . Data.Char.digitToInt $ c
       | otherwise = Nothing
```

This is what I wrote in the command line.

```
cabal update
cabal install --lib split
cd 'C:\Users\Username\Haskell Sudoku Solver'
ghci
:l Sudoku-Solver
```

And this is the error message that appears

```
Sudoku-Solver.hs:53:53: error:
    Not in scope: `Data.List.Split.chunksOf'
    No module named `Data.List.Split' is imported.
   |
53 |   | length s == 81 = traverse (traverse readCell) . Data.List.Split.chunksOf 9 $ s
   |                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I presumed 'cabal install --lib split' would have solved the problem but the error still appears nonetheless. Sorry for the very beginner level question.

Comment: Which version of cabal are you using? (`cabal --version`).

Comment: Do you have a `.cabal` file for your project? If yes, add `split` package into dependencies there.

Comment: @danidiaz I'm using version 3.2.0.0

Comment: @arrowd I do not have a `.cabal` file for my project, but I'll try to add one and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: @AlexandreGoncalves It seems that you forgot to import `Data.List.Split` in your code.

Comment: @danidaz I added `import Data.List.Split` at the top of the code just below `import Data.List` but I still get an error message. `Could not find module Data.List.Split` :(

Comment: If you do not want to create a `.cabal` file, call `ghci -package split`.

Comment: @AlexandreGoncalves When you start `ghci`, does a message like `Loaded package environment from...` appear?

Comment: @arrowd I managed to get a `.cabal` file, but I’m not sure where to add split into the dependencies. I also tried `git -package split`, but I got the error  `cannot satisfy -package split`. I also tried `git -package Data.List.Split`, but I got the same error unfortunately.

Comment: @danidiaz Nope, that message does not appear.

Comment: @AlexandreGoncalves If you go into an empty folder, type `cabal install --lib --package-env . split` and then start `ghci` in that same folder, does it work?

Comment: @danidiaz It worked! I typed in `cabal install --lib --package-env . split` into the empty folder and then the folder with the code. The loading message appeared on both, and the error message disappeared. Thanks for helping me with this silly problem @danidiaz and @arrowd

Comment: @AlexandreGoncalves Glad it helped. When one invokes `cabal install --lib` without an explicit `--package-env` location, `cabal` tries to create/update a GHC package environment file in a default location. But maybe it failed to do so in your case, possibly because of a permissions problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have both `cabal` and `stack` installed. I've tried `cabal` first, but it didn't help. I had the same problem as you. After installing using `cabal`, it was not available.

Using [Haskell Tool Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/) I was able to install `split`.

To install [Data.List.Split](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.4/docs/Data-List-Split.html), I use:

```bash
stack install split
```

The install log is:

```bash
Stack has not been tested with GHC versions above 8.10, and using 9.0.2, this may fail
Stack has not been tested with Cabal versions above 3.2, but version 3.4.1.0 was found, this may fail
split> configure
split> Configuring split-0.2.3.5...
split> build
split> Preprocessing library for split-0.2.3.5..
split> Building library for split-0.2.3.5..
split> [1 of 2] Compiling Data.List.Split.Internals
split> [2 of 2] Compiling Data.List.Split
split> copy/register
split> Installing library in /home/jgr/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/6726e8addea932d24fc8b50d70deb525054fafb232ea328ff9f6f683b340b2c8/9.0.2/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-9.0.2/split-0.2.3.5-7ZH2luRnI1Ks8lnSDjPo5
split> Registering library for split-0.2.3.5..
```

Test:

```bash
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded package environment from /home/jgr/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.8.4/environments/default
Prelude> import Data.List.Split
Prelude Data.List.Split> chunksOf 10 "GUCUACCUCCAUACCACCCUGAAUGUCCCCCGAUCUCGGAAGCUAAGCAGGGUCAGGCCUGGUUAGUACUUGGAUGGGACAAUAGGGCUAAGGUGAGUAGAUU"
["GUCUACCUCC","AUACCACCCU","GAAUGUCCCC","CGAUCUCGGA","AGCUAAGCAG","GGUCAGGCCU","GGUUAGUACU","UGGAUGGGAC","AAUAGGGCUA","AGGUGAGUAG","AUU"]
Prelude Data.List.Split> 
Leaving GHCi.
```