# How to find and use QuickCheck package since I forgot to use --lib while doing cabal install

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I wanted to use QuickCheck package so i did `cabal install QuickCheck` and then I got

```
Warning: You asked to install executables, but there are no executables in
target: QuickCheck. Perhaps you want to use --lib to install libraries
instead.
```

I then came to know that the right way to do it

```
cabal install --lib QuickCheck
```

I tried finding how to make it work after this but not able to find exact way. 
I am a beginner so any help would be nice.
Then I tried to to uninstall the package so that I can reinstall using --lib but that also yields problem.
I tried uninstalling using following

```
cabal uninstall QuickCheck
```

It gave this message

```
cabal.exe: This version of 'cabal-install' does not support the 'uninstall'
operation. It will likely be implemented at some point in the future; in the
meantime you're advised to use either 'ghc-pkg unregister QuickCheck' or
'cabal sandbox hc-pkg -- unregister QuickCheck'.
```

So then I tried this

```
ghc-pkg unregister --force QuickCheck
```

Then it says this

```
ghc-pkg: cannot find package QuickCheck
```

Any help or comment is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You wrote "I tried finding how to make it work after this but not able to find exact way". What was the concrete problem?

Comment: +1 for a well-formulated answer, although it's close to a duplicate to a couple of earlier ones. The big-picture answer is that the “right” way is to not use `cabal install` at all, instead make your own cabal project that _depends_ on `QuickCheck`. Then you can simply `cabal build` it and Cabal will handle any necessary installations automatically behind the scenes.

Comment: @danidiaz The problem was that on writing import statement for QuickCheck it does not recognize it and gives an error saying cannot find such a module.

Comment: @gauss_is_king If you try this trick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62357916/how-do-i-install-the-data-list-split-module-for-haskell#comment110286948_62357916 go into an empty folder, type `cabal install --lib --package-env . QuickCheck` and then start ghci in that same folder, does it work?

Comment: @danidiaz Yes it works with that added `--package-env` does that say something about the way have installed everything ?

Comment: @danidiaz Do you have any idea if the permissions problem that you spoke of in the link, has something to do with some changes needed to be made to the config file for cabal?

Comment: @gauss_is_king I'm not sure why is that happening. According to cabal docs https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/nix-local-build.html#cabal-v2-install the default package environment (when no `--package-env` is given) is `~/.ghc/$ARCH-$OS-$GHCVER/environments/default`. It could be a permissions issue, or perhaps there's a preexisting package environment that is being picked according to the lookup rules listed in https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-environments

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to remove it. Just run

```
cabal install --lib QuickCheck
```

It'll tell you it was already up to date, but it also will (silently) mark it as available outside of cabal-managed builds.

Demonstration:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.8.3: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded package environment from /home/carl/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.8.3/environments/default
Prelude> import Test.QuickCheck

<no location info>: error:
    Could not find module ‘Test.QuickCheck’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
Prelude>
Leaving GHCi.

$ cabal install QuickCheck
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-8.8.3 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - splitmix-0.0.5 (lib) (requires download & build)
 - QuickCheck-2.14 (lib) (requires download & build)
Downloading  splitmix-0.0.5
Downloaded   splitmix-0.0.5
Downloading  QuickCheck-2.14
Starting     splitmix-0.0.5 (lib)
Downloaded   QuickCheck-2.14
Building     splitmix-0.0.5 (lib)
Installing   splitmix-0.0.5 (lib)
Completed    splitmix-0.0.5 (lib)
Starting     QuickCheck-2.14 (lib)
Building     QuickCheck-2.14 (lib)
Installing   QuickCheck-2.14 (lib)
Completed    QuickCheck-2.14 (lib)

$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.8.3: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded package environment from /home/carl/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.8.3/environments/default
Prelude> import Test.QuickCheck

<no location info>: error:
    Could not load module ‘Test.QuickCheck’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘QuickCheck-2.14’.
    You can run ‘:set -package QuickCheck’ to expose it.
    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
Prelude>
Leaving GHCi.

$ cabal install QuickCheck --lib
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date

carl@DESKTOP-35ES091:~/hask$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.8.3: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded package environment from /home/carl/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.8.3/environments/default
Prelude> import Test.QuickCheck
Prelude Test.QuickCheck>
```

I started with QuickCheck not installed, so ghci gave the error `It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.` when I tried to import `Test.QuickCheck`. After installing it without the `--lib` option, I got the error `It is a member of the hidden package ‘QuickCheck-2.14’`.  When I installed with the `--lib` option, it told me it was already up to date, but afterwards importing `Test.QuickCheck` in ghci worked.

Yeah, `ghc-pkg list` still doesn't show it.  That command seems to be a bit out of date with the way `cabal install --lib` works now, and how ghc has been updated to make it work.

Comment: So after this, if I run `ghc-pkg list` QuickCheck should show up in the list ? Running this command doesn't seem to make any difference in my case, QuickCheck is still not recognized and doesn't show up in the list. I'm sorry I don't understand "it also will (silently) mark it as available outside of cabal-managed builds" is supposed to imply. Any clarification would be helpful.

Comment: @gauss_is_king Updated with a demonstration.  Looks like `ghc-pkg list` is out of date right now.